# python ctypes, callback function augment type is C++ reference

Tags: python, c++, c, ctypes

I integrate a dll to python by ctypes, the dll need set a callback function. But the dll callback function declare as below

```
void setCallBack(void(*)(Data &a))

Data is C struct, declare as below
typedef struct {
    int index,
    ....
}Data
```

I do not clear how to set it by ctypes, I try it as below, but return "WindowsError: [Error -1073741795] Windows Error 0xC000001D" error, could you help to give a example how to set the callback.

```
mydll = cdll.LoadLibrary("XXX.dll")  
callback_type = CFUNCTYPE(None, POINTER(Data))
callback = callback_type(Data)
mydll.setCallBack(callback)

def dataResponse(data):
    print data.index

class Data(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("index", c_int)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your structure looks correct, but if you're calling into a Windows API your calling convention is likely off (you're using cdecl, but if this is a Windows API call, you need stdcall).

Try replacing `mydll = cdll.LoadLibrary("XXX.dll")` with `mydll = WinDLL("XXX.dll")`

You may also need to provide a callback function that uses stdcall instead of cdecl. If so, switch `CFUNCTYPE` to `WINFUNCTYPE`. The API you're calling should provide details about what it expects.

And see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

One error is that your callback is wrapping your data structure, not your callback function.  Change:

```
callback_type = CFUNCTYPE(None, POINTER(Data))
callback = callback_type(Data)
mydll.setCallBack(callback)
def dataResponse(data):
    print data.index
```

to:

```
def dataResponse(data):
    print data.index
callback = callback_type(dataResponse)
mydll.setCallBack(callback)
```

Or you can use decorator syntax:

```
@CFUNCTYPE(None, POINTER(Data))
def dataResponse(data):
    print data.index

mydll.setCallBack(dataResponse)
```

Here's a complete example.  Also use `extern "C"` to avoid C++ name mangling:

**test.cpp (Windows)**

```
struct Data {
    int index;
};

typedef void (*CALLBACK)(Data&);
CALLBACK g_callback;

extern "C" {
    __declspec(dllexport)void setCallBack(CALLBACK f) {
        g_callback = f;
    }

    __declspec(dllexport) void func() {
        Data d;
        d.index = 42;
        if(g_callback)
            g_callback(d);
    }
}
```

**test.py**

```
from ctypes import *

class Data(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('index',c_int)]

CALLBACK = CFUNCTYPE(None,POINTER(Data))

dll = CDLL('test')
dll.setCallBack.argtypes = CALLBACK,
dll.setCallBack.restype = None
dll.func.argtypes = None
dll.restype = None

@CALLBACK
def dataResponse(data):
    print(data.contents.index)

dll.setCallBack(dataResponse)
dll.func()
```

**Output**

> ```
> 42
> ```

Answer (score 0):

ctypes does not work with Cpp it only works with C, your Cpp function need to have `extern "C"` linkage.
The reason that does not work has to do with Cpp name mangling. The name of your function `void setCallBack(void(*)(Data &a))` is mangled in Cpp as `_Z11setCallBackPFvR4DataE`, but if you put `extern "C"` in from of it (`extern "C" void setCallBack(void(*)(Data &a))`), it will C mangling rules, so it will be mangled as `setCallBack`.
So when you do `mydll.setCallBack` ctypes is looking for a function named `setCallBack` but it doesn't find it, it finds a function named `_Z11setCallBackPFvR4DataE` which it does not recognize and gives you an error.